# Subsitute only specific powers of a variable

Tags: matlab

I'm writing a simple MATLAB code to work with Field Extensions.

I'm using the symbolic package, and I want to take powers of a variable x and divide modulo 2, and substitute an x^3 = x + 1 but only for cubic powers of x. The mod part I've got figured out, but I can't get it to only substitute cubic powers. My code would look something like this:

```
for i = 1:7
a(i) = mod(x^i,2)
$$ some sort of if statement to substitute cubic powers of x when they arise$$
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: OK general question: why do you want to use the Symbolic Math Toolbox? from this snippet, there is no need for this. Second `if i == 3 a(i) = x+1 end` or am I getting your question wrong?

Comment: Maybe if I explain the technical problem it might be easier to understand:

I am working in the finite field K = F_2[x] / (x^3 + x + 1). I want a program that will write out the elements of the set of units K^x which happen to be \alpha^i for i = 1:7 where \alpha is the class of x in K. I also have that \alpha satisfies \alpha^3 = \alpha + 1. The elements of K^x (7 in total) are polynomials in \alpha with deg < 3.

I thought of using the Symbolic toolbox because the output should be polynomials in \alpha. What is the best way to go about this problem?

Comment: If you are applying operations within finite domain (Galois field), you can use `gfdeconv`, where your primitive polynomial  is `X^3 + X + 1`. More information can be found via `https://se.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/gfdeconv.html`